# Chrome "Did you mean to go to" banner

Tags: google-chrome, dns, url, google-search, brave

Whenever I search for a single-word term in Google via the Chrome omnibox, Chrome presents a suggestion to instead visit that term as an `http://`-prefixed "URL":

---

[image: Did you mean to go to ?]

> Did you mean to go to http://some-random-google-search/?

---

I've never seen this behavior from Chrome before, and it's quite annoying when searching. The pop-up banner is often delayed by 1-5 seconds and comes in well after the SERP has loaded.

I've only noticed this today when using my iPhone's Personal Hotspot tethered to my laptop.

---

Why is this banner being displayed by Chrome? Can I prevent the browser from displaying it for obviously non-URLs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I prevent the browser from displaying it for obviously non-URLs?

1. On your address bar, type `chrome://flags`.
2. On the search box type: `#enable-lookalike-url-navigation-suggestions`
3. Set it to Disable, then relaunch Chrome. The suggestions will stop appearing.

[image]

> Why is this banner being displayed by Chrome?

The explanation for this banner is extracted from the article sourced below:

> The Google Chrome browser is set to add a feature that will warn users when accessing sites with domain names that look like authentic websites.
>
> The feature has been in the works for quite some time at Google and is a response to the practice of using typosquatted domains or IDN homograph attacks to lure users on websites they didn't intend to access.
>
> For example, crooks often register misspelled versions of popular domains, such as paypall.com, or they'd use domains with Unicode characters like coịnbạse.com to host phishing pages and steal users' credentials.

**Source:** [Google Chrome to get warnings for 'lookalike URLs'](https://www.zdnet.com/article/google-chrome-to-get-warnings-for-lookalike-urls/)

Comment: Good answer for the fix. Can anyone give an explanation for why this is suddenly happening? DNS-related, I believe.

Comment: @pkamb See edit.

Comment: no such flag exists in Version 87.0.4280.88

Comment: @BuddyZ https://superuser.com/a/1612429/855367

Comment: appreciate the link Reddy. That let me access the flag, but unfortunately changing the enable-lookalike-url-navigation-suggestions still didn't have an effect on the browsing experience. Even after a restart, I still get the "did you mean to go to"

Comment: @BuddyZ Sorry iit did not work for you. A workaround (not the greatest solution) would be to remove chrome 87 and install 86 and find a way to stop it from upgrading.