# How to disable “#enable-lookalike-url-navigation-suggestions” in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Where do I go to find the `#enable-lookalike-url-navigation-suggestions` in Chrome to disable it? This option is not not showing up in `chrome://flags/`.

[image: Screenshot.]

Comment: What leads you to believe this is the correct name for this flag?

Comment: All the research I've done says that it's called that, and also i scrolled through the whole list of flags and nothing shows up that does anything like that

Comment: All the research I've done indicates this showed up as being in development a year ago. Nothing indicates it was ever released

Comment: Then how do i get rid of the "did you mean to go to https:example.com" when i type the word "example" in the url bar? I'm used to searching via the url bar instead of the google search box, and i dont want to have to change the way i search just because of one annoying popup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using version 87.0.4280.88, the flag is not present. It was present on version 86 under another name (#use-lookalike-for-navigation-suggestions) as shown on my answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/1583772/855367).

If you want to it to be listed, you have first to enable #temporary-unexpire-flags-m86. Then restart Chrome.

[image]

After restarting Chrome, search for #use-lookalike-for-navigation-suggestions.  It will be displayed, and you can disable it.

[image]

**But note that both flags, might not be listed in future releases of the browser.**

Answer (score 1):

Looking online indicates this flag and feature were being developed a year ago (multiple articles from January 2020). There is no indication it has been released.

Searching Chrome on my own systems I do not see the flag either.

Comment: The flag used to be [there](https://superuser.com/questions/1583759/chrome-did-you-mean-to-go-to-banner), but it seems it has been removed.